# Use JQ in Bash Azure Function

Tags: bash, azure, azure-functions, jq

Goal:

I have a Bash script that needs to run every 5 minutes. I am currently doing this with Windows Task Scheduler on an Azure VM. I would like to use an alternative to the VM to save cost. Azure Functions seems like a way.

Problem:

My Bash script uses JQ. I'd like to run the script in a Bash Azure Function (QueueTriggerBash). The script runs but doesn't execute the JQ commands. I assume this is because JQ is not recognized by the Azure Function.

I tried installing JQ with the JQ Linux instructions (`sudo apt-get install jq` - it does not recognize `sudo`), installing a JQ package with npm (it does not recognize `npm`), installing JQ with Chocolatey (it does not recognize `choco`) but these attempts were unsuccessful. My method for trying these was to include the command at the beginning of my script and running the Azure Function.

The reason the script is in Bash is that I don't know PS, C#, or JS. The reason for Azure Functions is that I have an Azure subscription. The script is not public.

Thank you for any help or ideas. If an Azure Function is not the best way to meet my goal I would be grateful to know.

Comment: I promise you this is going to be way easier in JavaScript, just invest a few hours, you won't regret it -- https://alligator.io/js/json-parse-stringify/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

technically you can use python venv to install jq, but generally speaking you can easily parse json with python\powershell\whatever. it doesnt take a lot of digging to do that.

Powershell parse json:

```
$json = az bla bla-bla bla-bla-bla
$jsonParsed = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonParsed.Property1[index].value
```

Python without jq:

```
import json
j = json.loads('{"one" : "1", "two" : "2", "three" : "3"}')
print j['two']
```

Python way to install modules:

https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/docs/install-python-modules.md

and after that you just add venv modules to path:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '../../../az/Lib/site-packages')))
```

assuming `../../../az/Lib/site-packages` is a relative path from you function root to the venv `site-packages` directory

Comment: Appreciate this @4c74356b41!